# How to solve how many times the ball collides with the corner

Tags: mathematics

In the cartesian coordinate system, four points (0, 0),(20, 0),(20, 19) and (0, 19) are used
as vertices to draw a rectangle. At first, a ball with negligible size is at the (0, 0) point. It then started
to move towards the point (2, 1). Every second, the ball passes the amount of distance between (0, 0)
to (2, 1). If it collides with one side of the rectangle, it follows the law of reflection and comes back
to the rectangle. If it collides with a corner, it again follows the law of reflection and comes back in
the direction it went in. Until the 2019th second, how many times will the ball collide with a corner
point?

Comment: Should this be the direction it went in, or should it be at a right angle to the direction it went in? I understand that it's a riddle, so some liberties may be taken with definitions, but the law of reflection states that the angle of reflection is equal to the angle of incidence, but on the opposite side of the line normal to the point of impact.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solution is:

> **10**

Reasoning:

> On X - every second the ball moves 2 units; it moves from 0 to 20 and after reaching 20, it returns to 0. So the ball reaches the left and the right edge every 10 seconds.
>
>   On Y - every second the ball moves 1 unit; it moves from 0 to 19 and after reaching 19, it returns to 0. So the ball reaches the top and the bottom edge every 19 seconds.
>
>   The ball collides with the corner when it collides with the X and Y edges at the same time.
>
>   For 10 and 19 the highest common divisor is 1, so the ball hits the corner every $10 \times 19 = 190$ seconds. 
>
>   $2019 \div 190 = 10.63$, so until the 2019th second it collides with the corners **10** times (start position is not included as collision).

Answer (score 4):

The ball bounces into a corner:

> 10 total times

The way I solved this was:

> First I drew the path on a grid, and noted that it takes 10 seconds traveling at (2, 1) per second to hit the right wall, at which point it would reverse its x direction and continue. I notated this as:
>  
>  `( 0, 0) + 10 * ( 2, 1) = 20, 10 [right wall, reverse x] 
>  (20,10) +  9 * (-2, 1) =  2, 19 [top wall, reverse y]
>  ( 2,19) +  1 * (-2,-1) =  0, 18 [left wall, reverse x]
>  ( 0,18) + 10 * ( 2,-1) = 20,  8 [right wall, reverse x]
>  (20, 8) +  8 * (-2,-1) =  4,  0 [bottom wall, reverse y]
>          +  2 * (-2, 1) =  0,  2`
>
>  For a total of 40 seconds to travel to (0, 2). Repeating this pattern, it will take 80 seconds to travel to (0, 4), 120 to (0, 6), and 160 to (0, 8).
>  Drawing this out, I saw that this would soon lead to the ball bouncing into the bottom right corner, so I calculated the times again starting from (0, 8):
>  
>  `+ 10 * (2, 1) = 20, 18
>  + 1 * (-2, 1) to 18, 19
>  + 9 * (-2, -1) to 0, 10
>  + 10 * (2, -1) to 20, 0`
>
>  For 30 more seconds or 190 seconds total to land in a corner. From here it would bounce back along the path it had made, and so it would hit a corner every 190 seconds. 2019 / 190 = 10.63, so we have 10 total bounces (not counting the first one). For reference, here is the image I created to map these bouncings (the lines alternate between red, blue, and green during bounces):
>  [The first 28 bounces](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gBy94.jpg)

Comment: Looks like I lost the speed race trying to brute-force an answer and then find a solution... I'm going to need a lot more practice formatting my markdown. Kudos to @Michał Wójcik for the much more elegant answer